# Unable to access static variable in JavaScript object that subclasses another JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript objects, one (Scope1.js) which "subclasses" another one (Scope2.js) by setting its prototype to the "base" object. Using alert, I can output the expected value for the static variable of the "base" object, but not for the "subclass" object.

Expected Output

```
Scope1.staticVar1:scope1
Scope2.staticVar2:scope2
```

Actual Output

```
Scope1.staticVar1:undefined
Scope2.staticVar2:scope2
```

Can somebody please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

Scope.html

```
<html>
    <head>                      
        <script src="Scope1.js"></script>
        <script src="Scope2.js"></script>
        <script>
            function Init() {
                alert("Scope1.staticVar1:"+Scope1.staticVar1);
                alert("Scope2.staticVar2:"+Scope2.staticVar2);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Init()"></body>
</html>
```

Scope1.js

```
function Scope1() {
    Scope2.call(this);
}
Scope1.prototype = Object.create(Scope2.prototype);
Scope1.staticVar1 = "scope1";
```

Scope2.js

```
function Scope2() {
}
Scope2.staticVar2 = "scope2";
```

Comment: You'd need to load the class that you're subclassing first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Scope1() {
     Scope2.call(this);
}
//Scope is undefined
//You should be using Scope1
Scope.prototype = Object.create(Scope2.prototype);
Scope.staticVar = "scope1";
```

You're assigning a static variable to `Scope` but `Scope` doesn't exist.
Just change `Scope` to `Scope1` and you're ready to go.

Then here's my next suggestion: switch your two script tags. The reasoning behind this is that the first script is loaded and ran before the second script. and the first script is referencing a piece of code in the second script before it loads.

I think what @The said was right though. It only transfers prototype variables I just tested this in my browser console. It does not transfer static variables.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I was already doing that - I messed up the code when I posted this. Anyway, I edited my code to reflect that - but the original question persists. Interestingly, if I remove the line - Scope1.prototype = Object.create(Scope2.prototype); - then it works as expected. I'm not understanding something here concerning prototypes.

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically, switch your two topmost script tags.

Comment: I think what The said was right though. It only transfers prototype variables I just tested this in my browser console.

Comment: Bingo! That fixes it. I will have to be cognizant of the order of my script tags in JavaScript - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment `Scope1.prototype = Object.create(Scope2.prototype);` will only set up the prototype inheritance chain for *instances* that are created of the subclass. The classes (constructor functions) themselves still do both inherit from `Function.prototype`.

You can use `Object.setPrototypeOf(Scope2, Scope1)` to fix that, or use ES6 classes (`class Scope2 extends Scope1`) to achieve this effect, but both will not work in old browsers.

In ES5, you can only copy over all properties manually, or just not use inherited static properties. When referring to a static property, you'd usually know which class it comes from anyway.